# AS3 -Error 1009 - Cannot access an object of null reference. So simple, wth is going on?

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-3

When I try to run this code with the main file being documentclass and the highest in the code heirarchy, it comes up with error 1009, but I cant see the problem. The playscreen class with the constructer function is there, in the same folder as the document class but document class is saying it is a null object reference. When I try to run the code with the main file being playscreen, there is no problem, it runs perfectly.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at playscreen()
at documentClass()
```

Here are my files:

```
DocumentClass:
package 
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class documentClass extends MovieClip
{
    public var playScreen:playscreen;

    public function documentClass():void
    {
        playScreen = new playscreen();
        addChild(playScreen);
    }
}
}
```

The playscreen class is too big to fit here and I dont want to trouble you with the details. But I can assure you it DOES exist and it is NOT null.

Comment: What line does the null reference error occur on?

Comment: Ill edit it in.. It doesnt say :/
This is the whole error:

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at playscreen()
 at documentClass()

Comment: From a style perspective you shouldn't be specifying a return type (even void) on a constructor and class names should be capitalized (PlayScreen). Aside from that though, it doesn't look like there's enough information to answer this question.

Comment: The error does not exist in the code sample you have posted. It is likely that the error exists in your playscreen class.

Comment: @user1266662: Compile with debugging info enabled (Ctrl+Shift+Enter). The message, by the way, is telling you the error is occurring inside the constructor of `playscreen`; the code you've posted here looks fine.

Comment: @Cameron You are a lifesaver. My playscreen() function was accessing the stage to add an event listener and I forgot to delete the unnecessary use of "stage". As stage was not accessable from the new heirarchy of 'playscreen', it could not be accessed and was returning a null object reference. Debug mode picked this right up.

Thank you very much :)

Comment: I take that back ^^ the use of 'stage' was necessary. What can I do to fix this? I need it for event listeners. 

My post with this question is here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699235/how-can-i-access-stage-outside-of-root-file

Comment: @psuedoFREAK: I see your new question has already been answered :-) Glad I could help.

Comment: if you check the `permit debugging` in the FLA settings, these errors will tell you exactly what line the error is occurring on

Answer (score 0):

Import the class

```
import myfolder.playscreen;
```

Comment: He said they're in the same folder, so no need for an import.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error that turned out to be a dependency loop. In my case I was referencing a subclass in the definition of a superclass, something like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public static const subclasses:Array = [ Don ];
}
```

and elsewhere

```
public class Don extends Person
{
}
```