# how can I access stage outside of root file?

Tags: actionscript-3

I fixed this error before where the source of the problem was that 'stage' was inaccessible from where I was putting the code (not in root). I deleted it and it ran fine, but the Event listeners that they were attatched to did not work anymore. I need these event listeners but when I try to put 'stage.' back infront it wont work. help?

This is what I had when it worked (when this file was still the root):

```
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keypressed);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyreleased);
```

Now my code is this, and it runs, just without the event listeners working:

```
        addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keypressed);
        addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyreleased);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `stage` property is `null` until the element is added to the stage. So you should first listen to the event `Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE`, and when you receive it, you can add your other event listeners:

```
addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStage);

function addedTostage():void
{
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStage);
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keypressed);
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyreleased);
}
```

Comment: So its getting the error because flash is reading through the entirety of all the files before executing them? Cool - thanks :P

Comment: @psuedoFREAK - No, it will execute the lines outside of functions when initializing the object. After the object is initialized, it will, eventually, be added to the stage.

Answer (score -1):

Use this to access the stage:

```
 var myMC:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
 addChild(myMC);
 var _stage:Stage = myMC.stage;
 trace("the AS3 Stage.width: "+_stage.stageWidth);
 trace("returns the width of objects on stage: "+_stage.width);
 trace("the AS3 Stage.height: "+_stage.stageHeight)
 trace("returns the height of objects on stage: "+_stage. height);
```

Source: http://www.iheartactionscript.com/stage-access-outside-of-documentroot-in-as3/

Comment: I already tried this method. Im still getting this error:

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at playscreen()[C:\Users\Callum\Desktop\Flash\Dance Dance destruction\classes\playscreen.as:85]
 at documentClass()[C:\Users\Callum\Desktop\Flash\Dance Dance destruction\classes\documentClass.as:12]
(all thats at playscreen.as:85 is the addeventlistener, for which im now using _stage.addEventListener....)

Comment: So you have a object that is null? is it the _stage variable? Can you trace this variable before calling the properties?